# glActiveTexture() throws GL_INVALID_ENUM

Tags: opengl

The  line

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+32);
```

throws GL_INVALID_ENUM (as I found running glGetError()), while

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+31);
```

runs fine.

According to [the documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml):

> "GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if texture is not one of GL_TEXTUREi, where i ranges from zero to the value of GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS minus one."

but in my case GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS is defined as 35661, and according to the same documentation

> "The number of texture units is implementation dependent, but must be at least 80."

How could I solve this problem?

Just in case, GL_TEXTURE0 is defined as 33984 and my version of OpenGL is 2.1

Comment: GL mandates 16 texture image units per-stage. GL 2.1 had exactly two stages (Vertex and Fragment). So rather than 80 (Vertex, Fragment, Tessellation Control, Tessellation Evaluation, Geometry - GL4) you have 32.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` may be defined as `35661`, but that's not what you want, thats the value of an enum (same as `GL_TEXTURE0` is defined as `33984`). These values have no meaning at all.

You get the number by querying `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &texture_units);`, which will return the number of textures you can use. It is very likely that it will be 32 on OpenGL 2.1 hw.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is a bit misleading. They mean the value retrieved by

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, ...)
```

not the value of the token itself.

Comment: thanks glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS, &data ) returns 32 in data... so I can have only 32 textures? isn't that too little?

Comment: @MatiasMorant: You're confusing textures with texture units. The number you got is the number of textures you can use at the same time drawing a single batch of geometry. Each of the texture units can hold a different texture. Textures are bound to texture units using glBindTexture

Comment: @MatiasMorant: Your code usually goes `foreach o in objects { for i in count(o.textures) { glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i); glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_…, o.textures[i]) } o.draw() }`